# Companion app terminated when enabling full access for keyboard

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm developing a custom keyboard extension for iOS and part of the companion (main) application is an on-boarding tutorial guiding the user through how to install the keyboard.

The final step in this tutorial is to enable full access in the device's settings, but doing so terminates my application:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9
```

Once the user returns to my application after enabling full access, he is supposed to continue the tutorial from where he left off. However, since the application was terminated, he must now start from the beginning again.

I could solve this with some clever (read *hacky*) hardcoded logic, however I would much rather the application not terminate when enabling full access.

My question is as follows: Is this intended functionality or a bug? Is there something I could do to prevent this from happening?

**Edit 1:**
I just wanted to point out that despite the *signal 9*, I do not believe this to be a memory issue with my app - the memory usage is extremely low, especially when the app is in the background. The application terminates exactly the same moment I press **Allow** on the *"Allow Full Access for..."* popup.

Comment: I have the same issue - Did you find a solution for this? If not: What was your clever/hacky solution?

Comment: @Bellovic I was not able to solve this myself. My solution is to persist a value when getting to the screen informing the user of the steps to take to install the keyboard, and when subsequently launching the app later read this value and check if the keyboard has been successfully installed. Depending on the value and whether the keyboard is installed, I determine which page to show to give the illusion that the user went through to the next page